# Shortest path on Riemannian manifold with boundary

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. Let $x\in \partial M$. Let $v\in T_x(\partial M)$ be a unit vector tangent to the boundary. Assume
$$II_{\partial M}(v)<0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,\, (1)$$
where $II_{\partial M}$ denotes the second fundamental form of the boundary.

Let $\gamma\colon [0,l]\to \partial M$ be a normalized geodesic on the boundary which starts at $x$ in the direction $v$.

> Is it true that if $l$ is sufficeintly small then $\gamma$ is a shortest path in $M$ (rather than in $\partial M$)? A reference would be very helpful.

Here the condition (1) seems to be crutial.

Remark: I think I have a proof of the positive answer to the question when $n=2$.